# What was the influence of the 'Legion of Doom' and the e-zine Phrack on early computer culture?

Tags: history

I was reading a bit about the 'Hacker Manifesto' written by Loyd 'The Mentor' Blakenship and was also reading about the hacker group 'Legion of Doom' and was wondering what influence these groups / people had on early computer culture.

I'm especially curious as to how the freedom of information attitudes that where common in these early groups filtered down into more mainstream attitudes to open source software / information.

Comment: An interesting question, but _awfully_ broad! The question might be treated a little more kindly if you would link to references and give dates, so that at least the question itself serves as a documentary tool.

Comment: If you are really interested in early computer culture, I would recommend the book "Hackers: Heroes of the Computer Revolution" by Steven Levy.  I'm old enough to have experience the late 70's and 1980's first hand, so when I first read the book back in the 1990's, I was blown away by how many of the attitudes, ideas and memes could be traced back to the 50's and 60's.  It's a fun read, and you will quickly see how MIT students sharing code on punch cards is the very first 'open source' repository...  Information should be free, open, shared, and accessible.  Great book.

Comment: Ok, I have made an attempt at a edit to make it less broad. I really hope this does not get closed.

Comment: The Jargon File is an amazing resource for anyone interested in the origins of computer culture.  http://catb.org/jargon/html/